# Checking for a running process and if its not found, starting it

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a short script to run each morning on a machine to check for two programs and if they aren't running, to start them. I've made this:

```
$process = "ProcessToStart"
$check = Get-Process $process
$executable = "ProcessFilePath"

if (!($check)) {
    Start-Process $executable
    Send-MailMessage -From "Machine" -To "IT" -Subject "Program was restarted" -Body "The program wasnt running" -SMTP "mail.blah.com"
}

$process = "outlook"
$executable = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\outlook.exe"

if (!($check)) {
    Start-Process $executable
    Send-MailMessage -From "Machine" -To "IT" -Subject "Program was restarted" -Body "The program wasnt running" -SMTP "mail.blah.com"
}
```

The problem I have is, last week it worked, and only launched/emailed if the process wasn't running. I've retested it this week and it's launching and emailing even if the processes are already running and I can't figure out what's different.

Comment: First troubleshooting step: Try and reproduce it interactively! Launch powershell, do `$process = "processname";$check = Get-Process $process` - does `$check` contain anything?

Comment: Yes, using outlook as the process name it returns a small table. If I close outlook and try it again it gives me an error saying it can't find the process.

Comment: The problem here is that he uses `$check` in both if statements without reassigning it.

Comment: I think you just fixed it. My assumption was that the `$check` variable I was using was the same for both so I would only need to reassign the `$process` and the `$executable` as they were different. I've literally just copy pasted the `$check` variable in so its identical to the first set and it hasn't launched multiple instances and hasn't emailed me. Thanks so much!